# Is there any Wso2 web github project for datamapper

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

Wso2 EI is having only eclipse designer for data mapper mediator but I am trying to build data mapper in my web project by which I wanted only javascript code to be generated(dmc).

Is there any reference project by using which I can develop drag and drop code generation (javascript code to be generated .dmc file) as eclipse project for plugin development is bit harder to understand or any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In new EI development, the idea is to design all the EI artifacts from EI tooling. Therefore, the Data Mapper was designed to be developed from EI Tooling (with Eclipse based Dev Studio). There is no JavaScript implementation available for Data Mapper.